# Obout Grid Style and Javascript not loading

Tags: jquery, load, grid, styles, obout

i set up my obout grid with styles and scripts and everything worked fine.

now i wanted to put the grid into a seperate aspx file (including scripts, datasources, etc) and load the grid page into the default page with jQuerys load method.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#divGrid').load("Grid.aspx #result", function () {
                $('#loader').hide('slow');
            });
        });
```

the script tag is included in the result div.

the grid page itself works, but the loaded grid in the default page is not loaded correctly. the scripts and styles are missing.

i tried to set up the folderstyle to "~/styles/black_glass" but that doesn't work too.

any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok now i see what the problem is.

that gridview generated some WebResource.axd and ScriptResource.axd includes for the resources in the grid page, which were not loaded via the jquery load call. if i remove the element selector in the load method, it works. this is not nice in this case, but thats a different thing to deal with.